# Javascript canvas won't draw from script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, parameter-passing

I've made a hexagon out of hexagons on a canvas and it works perfectly, when I change it's size in the script and refresh the page. Of course it needs to change size on the go, so I put an input number field, but when I try to give the size from the html to the script the next thing happen:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
 function size()
 {
  return document.getElementById('myNumber').value;
 }
 
 function drawHex(ctx, x, y)
 { 
  var side = 0;
  var size = 10;
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + size * Math.cos(0), y + size * Math.sin(0));
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#D1CBCA";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#CCCCCC";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  
  for (side; side < 7; side++)
  {
   ctx.lineTo(x + size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6), y + size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
  }
  
  ctx.fill();
 }
 
 function drawSixHex(ctx, x, y)
 {
  drawHex(ctx, x, y);
  drawHex(ctx, x-16, y+10);
  drawHex(ctx, x-16, y-10);
  drawHex(ctx, x+16, y+10);
  drawHex(ctx, x+16, y-10);
  drawHex(ctx, x, y+2*10);
  drawHex(ctx, x, y-2*10);
 }
 
 function drawBoard(x, y, ctx, m)
 {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,980,520);
  var oldX = x;
  var oldY = y;
   
  var diffX = 16;
  var diffY = 10;
  
  for (var i = 1; i<=(2*m+1); i++)
  {
   for (var j = 0; j<m+1; j++)
   {
    if(i%2!=0)
    {
     drawHex(ctx, oldX+i*diffX, oldY-diffY+2*j*diffY);
    }
    else
    {
     drawHex(ctx, oldX+i*diffX, oldY+2*j*diffY);
    }
   } 
  }
  
  for(var k = 1; k<m; k=k+2)
  {
  
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(k+2)*diffX, oldY-k*diffY);
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(k+2)*diffX, (oldY+2*m*diffY)+(k-2)*diffY);
   
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(m-1)*diffX+(k+2)*diffX, oldY+(k-(m-1))*diffY);
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(m-1)*diffX+(k+2)*diffX, (oldY+2*m*diffY)-(k-(m-3))*diffY);
  
  }
 
  for(var g = -2*m; g<2*m-2; g=g+2)
  {
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX + (m+1)*diffX, oldY+(g)*diffY+(m+1)*diffY);
  }
  
 }
 
 var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 
 drawBoard(250, 250, ctx, size());
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Canvas Hexagonal Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="980" height="520" ></canvas>
   <br>
   <br>
   
   
 
   <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="6" min="3" max="8">
   <button onclick="size()">Try it</button>
   
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   
   
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you are just returning the size via size function.. instead you should re draw canvas with that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `size()` into a number.  Added `+` in front of size():

```js
function size()
 {
  return +(document.getElementById('myNumber').value);
 }
 
 function drawHex(ctx, x, y)
 { 
  var side = 0;
  var size = 10;
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + size * Math.cos(0), y + size * Math.sin(0));
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#D1CBCA";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#CCCCCC";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  
  for (side; side < 7; side++)
  {
   ctx.lineTo(x + size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6), y + size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
  }
  
  ctx.fill();
 }
 
 function drawSixHex(ctx, x, y)
 {
  drawHex(ctx, x, y);
  drawHex(ctx, x-16, y+10);
  drawHex(ctx, x-16, y-10);
  drawHex(ctx, x+16, y+10);
  drawHex(ctx, x+16, y-10);
  drawHex(ctx, x, y+2*10);
  drawHex(ctx, x, y-2*10);
 }
 
 function drawBoard(x, y, ctx, m)
 {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,980,520);
  var oldX = x;
  var oldY = y;
   
  var diffX = 16;
  var diffY = 10;
  
  for (var i = 1; i<=(2*m+1); i++)
  {
   for (var j = 0; j<m+1; j++)
   {
    if(i%2!=0)
    {
     drawHex(ctx, oldX+i*diffX, oldY-diffY+2*j*diffY);
    }
    else
    {
     drawHex(ctx, oldX+i*diffX, oldY+2*j*diffY);
    }
   } 
  }
  
  for(var k = 1; k<m; k=k+2)
  {
  
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(k+2)*diffX, oldY-k*diffY);
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(k+2)*diffX, (oldY+2*m*diffY)+(k-2)*diffY);
   
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(m-1)*diffX+(k+2)*diffX, oldY+(k-(m-1))*diffY);
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(m-1)*diffX+(k+2)*diffX, (oldY+2*m*diffY)-(k-(m-3))*diffY);
  
  }
 
  for(var g = -2*m; g<2*m-2; g=g+2)
  {
   drawSixHex(ctx, oldX + (m+1)*diffX, oldY+(g)*diffY+(m+1)*diffY);
  }
  
 }
 
 var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 function draw(){
   drawBoard(250, 250, ctx, +size());
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Canvas Hexagonal Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="980" height="520" ></canvas>
   <br>
   <br>
   
   
 
   <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="6" min="3" max="8">
   <button onclick="draw()">Try it</button>
   
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   
   
  </body>
 </html>
```

Note it sort of seems to work but acts funny, because the comparison operators are doing an implicit conversion before comparing, so you get lexical comparisons where "15"<"125" returns false, but you expect 15<125 to return true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the dom has already rendered and doesnt "re-render" once there's a value update. There's many ways to implement a solution. Here one approach. **NOTE**: you may need to scroll down to input a value. If you find this helpful please mark down as answer. Thanks

```js
function resize()
{
    var SIZE = document.getElementById('myNumber').value;
    drawBoard(250, 250, ctx, SIZE);
    return 
}

function drawHex(ctx, x, y)
{ 
    var side = 0;
    var size = 10;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + size * Math.cos(0), y + size * Math.sin(0));

    ctx.fillStyle = "#D1CBCA";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#CCCCCC";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    for (side; side < 7; side++)
    {
        ctx.lineTo(x + size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6), y + size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
    }

    ctx.fill();
}

function drawSixHex(ctx, x, y)
{
    drawHex(ctx, x, y);
    drawHex(ctx, x-16, y+10);
    drawHex(ctx, x-16, y-10);
    drawHex(ctx, x+16, y+10);
    drawHex(ctx, x+16, y-10);
    drawHex(ctx, x, y+2*10);
    drawHex(ctx, x, y-2*10);
}

function drawBoard(x, y, ctx, m)
{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,980,520);
    var oldX = x;
    var oldY = y;

    var diffX = 16;
    var diffY = 10;

    for (var i = 1; i<=(2*m+1); i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j<m+1; j++)
        {
            if(i%2!=0)
            {
                drawHex(ctx, oldX+i*diffX, oldY-diffY+2*j*diffY);
            }
            else
            {
                drawHex(ctx, oldX+i*diffX, oldY+2*j*diffY);
            }
        }   
    }

    for(var k = 1; k<m; k=k+2)
    {

        drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(k+2)*diffX, oldY-k*diffY);
        drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(k+2)*diffX, (oldY+2*m*diffY)+(k-2)*diffY);

        drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(m-1)*diffX+(k+2)*diffX, oldY+(k-(m-1))*diffY);
        drawSixHex(ctx, oldX+(m-1)*diffX+(k+2)*diffX, (oldY+2*m*diffY)-(k-(m-3))*diffY);

    }

    for(var g = -2*m; g<2*m-2; g=g+2)
    {
        drawSixHex(ctx, oldX + (m+1)*diffX, oldY+(g)*diffY+(m+1)*diffY);
    }

}

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Canvas Hexagonal Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="980" height="520" ></canvas>
        <br>
        <br>



        <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0" min="3" max="8">
        <button onclick="resize()">Try it</button>

        <script src="script.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's still produces the same problem. The hexagon starts to grow for no reason. The problem may be the way I give drawBoard() the parameter from which I draw the whole hex.

Comment: there a default value of 6 if you don't want it to render with a default value change it to 0

Comment: I think he's saying that the drawing doesn't match his expected output.  He says something about a "hexagon out of hexagons" in the OP.  His hexagon layout is bugged.